# How can I get the exponent of each number in a np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have the array:

```
x = np.array([0.00001,0.001])
```

numpy will make the numbers to

```
array([  1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-03])
```

Now I want to get the exponents, something like

```
x.get_exponent()
```

with result

```
[-5,-3]
```

Comment: `np.log10(x)` will give you that, but I don't think that is exactly what you want.  What you you expect if x is, e.g.,  `array([0.0000025, 0.09])`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x)))`.

For example:

```
In [13]: x = np.array([0.00001, -0.001, 0.0000025, 0.09, -13.25, 9876.5])

In [14]: x
Out[14]: 
array([  1.00000000e-05,  -1.00000000e-03,   2.50000000e-06,
         9.00000000e-02,  -1.32500000e+01,   9.87650000e+03])

In [15]: np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x))).astype(int)
Out[15]: array([-5, -3, -6, -2,  1,  3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [log10](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#numpy.log10)

```
In [49]: x = np.array([0.00001,0.001])
In [50]: np.log10(x)
Out[50]: array([-5., -3.])
```

Comment: That doesn't work if the number is isn't evenly divisible by 10.

Comment: try your answer with `np.array([0.00005,0.006])`. The answers are not the exponent of the floating point number....

Comment: @talonmies, I got the point -- but when I answered I thougt the OP was just asking for log10 -- after all this wasn't immediately clear from the question (at least to me) -- but I couldn't withstand to point out that `0.00001` is not divisible by 10, sorry...