# Matlab fprintf to keep significant figures and rightmost zeroes

Tags: matlab, formatting, string-formatting

Let's say I have a random variable `a=1.2400`, and I want to print it with four significant figures, i.e., 1.240. How would I go about that?

```
fprintf('%0.4g',a) % drops rightmost zero
fprintf('%0.3f',a) % give too many sig figs if a >= 10
```

Using `'%g'` drops the important zeros, and with `'%f'` I can only specify the number of digits after the decimal, which results in too many significant figures if, say, `a=10.04`. I'm not too familiar with formatting ,but there has to be a simple method. I haven't found it in my searches.

Comment: So if `a = 234.56`, do you want the output to be `234.6`?

Comment: Yes essentially. Rounding would be nice, but is not necessary here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values to be printed are all less than 10000, you can do the following. (Sorry, only tested in octave.)

```
octave:62> a = 1.24
a =  1.2400
octave:63> sprintf('%.*f\n', 3-floor(log10(abs(a))), a)
ans = 1.240

octave:64> a = 234.56
a =  234.56
octave:65> sprintf('%.*f\n', 3-floor(log10(abs(a))), a)
ans = 234.6
```

For more about the expression `floor(log10(abs(a)))`, see [How can I get the exponent of each number in a np.array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509626/how-can-i-get-the-exponent-of-each-number-in-a-np-array/14509780#14509780)

If you don't mind exponential notation, another alternative is to use `'%.3e'` to always get the same number of signficant digits:

```
octave:70> a = 1.24
a =  1.2400
octave:71> sprintf('%.3e\n', a)
ans = 1.240e+00

octave:72> a = 234.56
a =  234.56
octave:73> sprintf('%.3e\n', a)
ans = 2.346e+02
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build on the answer by Warren, and I wrote a function that should work for both small and large numbers alike. Perhaps someone will improve on this, but I am pleased with it.

```
function str=sigfigstr(a,sigfigs)

numdecimal = floor(log10(abs(a)));

if sigfigs - numdecimal < 0
    str=sprintf('%.0f',round(a,sigfigs,'significant'));
else
    str=strip(sprintf('%.*f\n', sigfigs-floor(log10(abs(a))), a));
end
```

Here are a few examples if it in action in Matlab

```
>> sigfigstr(.000012431634,3)
ans = '0.0000124'
>> sigfigstr(26666,3)
ans = '26700'
```